# Не переведено сообщение о завершении конкурса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

При завершении конкурса по конкурсному вопросу, в "Последних входящих сообщениях" высвечивается сообщение "Конкурс скоро закончится" "Your bounty on question "%QUSESTION_TOPIC%" is completed. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours."

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Ваш конкурс по вопросу "%QUSESTION_TOPIC%" завершён. Вы должны назначить победителя в течение 24 часов.

Comment: Кстати, а посему заголовок - "Конкурс скоро закончится"? Во-первых с маленькой буквы, во-вторых он _уже_ завершен, исходя из тела сообщения. Да и вообще все заголовки с маленькой, кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас это переведено (и используется) так:

> Ваш конкурс к вопросу "$questionTitle$" завершён. Вы должны присудить приз в течение 24 часов.